# Error "defines an Unary Operator as aggregation type but is missing member property '@UO'"

Tags: iccube

I am using Unary Operator as Aggregation Type to calculate Measure and defining Rollup Hierarchy and it is working fine till data is present in underlying tables.

But getting below error if underlying table doesn't have any data.

The rollup hierarchy '[LR Structures].[LR Structures]' in measure '_LR Amount 1' defines an Unary Operator as aggregation type but is missing member property '@UO'

I have already defined the Unknown member as 'Unknown'

Answer (score 0):

From icCube 6.8.6, this validity check will be relaxed for "empty" hierarchies used as rollup. It is left up to the user not to use the corresponding measures.